# Whenever we install a new version of the app, we are losing old data. How can we access old data in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, css, android-studio

When I uninstall my app the original data is lost. When I re-install the app how do I get my old data in Android Studio?

I have tried as my app link is added to my Google account.

I only want an answer in Android Studio as my app is running in Android Studio with Java.

Comment: what you are using for saving data?

Comment: SQlite database

Comment: Okay, Might be some where you are clearing data,otherwise it will never clear even after new version update.
put some code her to know more.

Comment: if you want prefer my SQlite  example, compare with yours.

https://github.com/sunilparmar04/SQLiteDemo

Comment: import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.drawtyme.utils.Log;
import com.example.gokulkri.myapplication3.datastructures.Session;